# How to stop Event Machine in setup like this?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

I have a Sinatra app, overall configured like described here [sinatra docs](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/embed/event-machine).

It basically starts an event machine loop.

Now, If I want to write a RSpec test, how do I start server like this and shutdown it after?

I can do this from console by `ruby server.rb`, I may execute this command from spec file in test suit setup (however, I'm not sure if it is right). But then, even if I do so, how I stop it after? (and do I need or it will be stopped after test is finished?)

Answer (score 0):

I think, in any case, you can use `Rack::Test` to test your Sinatra app. In order to run the specs, you don't need to run the server from the terminal.

Take a look at the documentation, you can find different examples:
http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html

Comment: I need to test some EM logic inside response blocks